# This program output should be 11

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int *(intArray+3);
int i;
int (intArray+3)=&i;
*(intArray+3)=11;
printf("%d%d",i,*(intArray+3));
getch();
```

in this program i used the concept *(intArray+3)=intArray[3]
with base program

```
int *p;
int i;
p=&i;
*p=11;
printf("%d%d",i,*p);
```

in this case o/p is 11,11 but 1st program is based on this concept plez help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. The C code you show will not compile for numerous reasons. Please provide compilable code before asking questions — see how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: if intArray is of int const * type, you cannot change the address.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer arithmetic is possible only after defining and initializing a pointer. Now let me explain it:

Suppose there an array `intArray` of 5 elements ;

```
int intArray[5];
```

Let's assume the starting address of `intArray` is `2000`. Now what `(intArray + 3)` does mean here? It means that `(intArray + 3)` is now referring to the fourth element (element 3) of the array `intArray`, i.e, now it is pointing to the location `2012` (as array name can be used as a pointer to its first element), assuming an `int` type is taking `4` bytes on a machine. When you place a `*` operator before it then it dereferences the value at that location, i.e, `*(intArray + 3)` will give you the value stored at the location `2012` which is equivalent to `intArray[3]`.
Since you declared `intArray` neither as a pointer (for pointer it must be initialized) nor as an array, you can't dereference `(intArray + 3)`. This is invalid and program will not compile.